TypeScript return type double arrow (Observable)?
I'm confused with this one:
const loadData: (detailsStore: RecipeDetailsStore) => (source$: Observable<string>) => Observable<RecipeDetails>

How can I interprete this?
My interpretation is:
loadData is a function which accept an argument from type RecipeDetailsStore and then it returns another function which takes a parameter named source$ of type Observable<string> and finally in the end the return type is an Observable from type RecipeDetails?`I am not sure.
or does it mean that loadData is a function and the return type is (detailsStore: RecipeDetailsStore) => (source$: Observable<string>) => Observable<RecipeDetails> ?
I'm confused about the double arrow?
I tried ask ChatGPT but he cannot answer this question and is confused as well and is stucked in an infinity loop (never had this before with ChatGPT).

There's definitely some code missing from that line, because nothing is actually assigned to loadData which isn't valid for a const declaration.

Your first interpretation is correct.
The second one will mean that you need a third arrow, and would look something like this:
let loadData: () => (detailsStore: RecipeDetailsStore) => (source$: Observable<string>) => Observable<RecipeDetails>

Like @John Montgomery stated, you cannot have a const without an assignment. You could use let instead;

I see. So I can write it like this too? let loadData = function(detailStore: RecipeDetailsStore): (source$: Observable<string>) => Observable<RecipeDetails> { ... }

Yes, this is equivalent to your first interpretation, and now you can safely use const as there is an assignment.
